# What is this blue/violet flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

I found this blue/violet flower on an acre in the Polder of Holland. It was growing in a sunflower field. The picture was taken in mid-october.
[image: Dutch flower with blue/violet blossom]

Comment: Do you have a picture of the leaves, and the entire plant? That would help

Comment: Sadly no. but you can see two leaves at the bottom of the picture.

Comment: How tall was it?, and by two leaves, do you mean the broad leaves in back of the picture, or the smaller, composite leaf in the foreground at the bottom?

Comment: The smaller composite leaf in the foreground. Stephie seems to have hit the nail on the head though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [Phacelia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phacelia).

Contrary to your tags, this is no wildflower, but planted either as bee food or to be tilled under as fertilizer. As your specimen blooms late in the year, I suspect the latter use, probably some seeds were blown away.